# decrement session time value using javascript and assign to label text

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have used this function to get `session timeout` from web.config file.

```
function readwebconfig() {
        var sessiontime = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
        document.getElementById('lblmsg').innerHTML = sessiontime;
    }
```

it is returning some numeric value, now i want to `decrement` this value by using javascript. and display this value like `9Min :30Sec's.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Some numeric value" Example please? If milliseconds you can do `var d = new Date(sessionTime);` and use d.getHours() and d.getMinutes()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As the session timeout is in minute, first add the current date with session timeout values and then show countdown to the user.

**JS:-**

```
var sessionTimeout = <%= Session.Timeout %> ;
var now = new Date();
var kickoff = now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + parseInt(sessionTimeout));

function updateWCTime() {
    now = new Date();

    diff = kickoff - now;

    days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
    secs = Math.floor(diff / 1000);

    mm = mins - hours * 60;
    ss = secs - mins * 60;

    document.getElementById("txt")
        .innerHTML = mm + ' minutes ' + ss + ' seconds';
}
setInterval(updateWCTime, 1000);
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div id="txt">
    </div>
```

Comment: @BhaskerVengala - Does this answer your query?